# Intent Fragment . how to used Intent In Fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation

I'm using a interface to switch from recycler View to details activitas. my interface function works. position is coming. But I can't switch to Details Activity. I think the soproduct is from context. How can I solve this problem? Thank you

```
class OrderFragment : Fragment() , OnMovieClickListener {

private lateinit var linearLayoutManager: LinearLayoutManager
private lateinit var adapter: RvAdapter

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    val view : View =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_order, container, false)
    val orderApiService = OrderApiService()
    val api = orderApiService.getDataa(requireActivity())

    api.myOrdersAssigned().enqueue(object : Callback<List<BaseModel>?> {
        override fun onResponse(
            call: Call<List<BaseModel>?>,
            response: Response<List<BaseModel>?>
        ) {

            val arrayOrder = response.body()
            val layoutManager: LinearLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
            recyclerViewMyOrders.setLayoutManager(layoutManager)
            adapter = RvAdapter(arrayOrder as ArrayList<BaseModel>,this@OrderFragment)
            recyclerViewMyOrders.setAdapter(adapter)
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

            if(response.isSuccessful){
                response.body()?.let {

                }
            }
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<BaseModel>?>, t: Throwable) {
            print(t.message.toString())
        }
    })

    return view
}

override fun onMovieItemClicked(position: Int) {
    println("Clicked  :  " + position.toString())
    val intent = Intent(requireContext().applicationContext,DetailsActivity::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

}

My Interface Function :

```
override fun onMovieItemClicked(position: Int) {
    println("Clicked  :  " + position.toString())
    val intent = Intent(requireContext().applicationContext,DetailsActivity::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create your variable Context inside your Fragment like this :

```
   private Context context;
```

Than you initialize it inside `onCreateView` like this :

```
context = view.getContext();
```

And insite you functio, instead of calling `requireContext().applicationContext` as parameter, call `context`

The code in on Java but you can easily convert it to Kotlin

Answer (score 0):

I have a question first: why don't you use the DetailFragment instead of a whole new Activity (because your OrderFragment and Detail can be both in a single Activity)

### Still want to use Activity

On your interface's override method, try to change `requireContext().applicationContext` to `requireContext()` only. Please reply me your `println` works or not.

### Change to Fragment

I know 2 ways to move to another fragment programmatically:

```
parentFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
      .replace<DestinationFragment>(R.id.fragmentContainer)

findNavController().navigate(action) // if you are using Navigation Components
```

### P/s:

I'm also a Android newbie and I see something can be improved in your source code, please correct me if I have something wrong

- Adapter and LinearLayoutManager don't have to be a class's property because you no longer need to use them outside API call, so just change their scope to inside `onResponse()`
- I have suffered from doing things with view in `onCreateView()` (because they are not fully inflated yet ?), so considering move your logic to `onViewCreated()` for a safe bet.